# How to re-arrange group on Outlook Ribbon using vsto add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, ribbonx

I have two groups, call them A and B, added to a ribbon in outlook. Each group has an id and a button or two inside. The A group uses the attribute 'insertAfterMso' to insert after the Show group  (GroupShow) in the ribbon. I can use the insertAfterMso attribute again for my B group, but I want it to always be after my A group and I can't get the insertAfterMso attribute to work with my custom control.

I have tried InsertAfterMso and InsertAfterQ giving the A group an IdMso and IdQ but neither work. What is the appropriate way to ensure that group B will show up just to the right of Group A?

Before anyone says it, I know that they will follow the order they are written in in the XML, but I have already moved group A. So... all of the other native groups exist in between my two custom groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to follow or come before a user created group. I used insertBeforeMso and insertAfterMso and used the built in outlook groups.

The office 2010 control names can be found here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627